# Como resolver esse problema: Expected '{' in body of function declaration

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Estou tentando imprimir um hello world e não consigo. Na verdade coloquei o hello world no lugar do que preciso imprimir para testar e continua dando o erro.

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ForecastingViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var fcstCreationDate: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var fcstLastRun: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var fcstUsedModel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var fcstNotes: UITextView!

    print("Hello World!")
```

recebo a mensagem Expected '{' in body of function declaration na linha do print.

Comment: Poderia colocar o código completo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A chamada ao método *print* tem que ser feita de dentro de algúm metodo da sua classe:

```
class ForecastingViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        print("Hello World!")
    }
}
```